# R loop Markov matrix transformation which doesn't work

Tags: r

I have this short function which should :

1. Take the transformation matrix, the initial vector and the number of transformations
2. Calculate resulting vectors and stack them in a data frame
3. Plot the data frame variables and return the data frame

Here is my function :

```
###### initvec _ initial vector
###### matrv _ transformation matrix
###### ns _ number of simulations
markovforplot<-function(initvec,matrv,ns) {
  ns <- as.integer(ns)
  initvec <- c()
  exposant <- c(1:ns)

  for (i in 1:ns) {
    library(expm)
    toprint<-apply((matrv %^% i)*initvec,2,sum)
    dataf <- data.frame(exposant=exposant,toprint=toprint)
    plot(dataf$exposant, dataf$toprint, type="l")
  }
  return(dataf)
}
```

When testing with properly formatted matrix and vector

```
(markovforplot(initvec=initvec,matrv=m,ns=20)
```

the error returned is :

```
Error in apply((matrv %^% i) * initvec, 2, sum) : 
  dims [product 16] do not match the length of object [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has the line:

```
R> initvec <- c()
R> initvec
NULL
```

This sets `initvec` to be an empty vector, i.e. over riding  your passed arguments.